# Is the universal wavefunction globally coherent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, interference, decoherence, coherence

In Wikipedia's article on [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence), it states that despite decoherence creating the appearance of wavefunction collapse,

> A total superposition of the global or universal wavefunction still exists (and remains coherent at the global level), but its ultimate fate remains an interpretational issue.

Most of this makes sense to me, but what I'm struggling with is the claim made in the parentheses. **Is the universal wavefunction globally coherent?**

At first glance, it makes sense for it to be. Since the universal wavefunction describes *everything*, there's no external environment for it to interact with to cause decoherence. On the other hand, the fact that it's globally coherent would lead me to believe that the different global quantum states of the universe (describing parallel universes) can [interfere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference#Quantum_interference) with each other, which I highly doubt is the case.

I asked a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572079/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat-are-the-different-quantum-states-inside-the-box-coherent-befo) in the context of the Schrödinger's Cat thought experiment and the responses which I got there seemed to suggest that a quantum system can lose its global coherence just by interacting *with itself*, which I also highly doubt is the case.

What am I missing? Perhaps the relationship between the coherence of quantum states and their ability to interfere with each other is more complicated than I thought. How does this work?

Edit: I am aware of the fact that wavefunction collapse does not occur under the Many-Worlds Interpretation.

Comment: Why do you "highly doubt" that the different worlds in MWI can interfere?

Comment: @lippiefanus Because wouldn't that have observable effects on the evolution of the universe, allowing us to detect the existence of alternate quantum realities with different histories from our own?

Comment: We see these effects all the time, for instance in the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect.

Comment: @flippiefanus I'm sorry, I must not have been very clear. By "worlds," I was referring to the MWI's claim that superpositions continue to exist following apparent wavefunction collapse, entailing the existence of alternate realities containing alternate versions of you and me. Any phenomenon which demonstrates interference between these realities (and I'm fairly sure that the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect doesn't do this) would empirically disprove the Copenhagen interpretation, which I know hasn't happened.

Comment: My understanding of MWI (which may be incorrect) is that there is no quantum collapse. So I don't understand this claim.The alternative versions of you or me is perhaps a bit of a stretch. What we perceive as you and me may involve all the worlds together with these interference. It may just be the we cannot see these interference effects because they are too subtle. Therefore, we cannot proof or disprove any of the interpretations.

Comment: @flippiefanus It's true that in the MWI the wavefunction never collapses. But [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) plays a similar role, causing alternate quantum states to become "out of phase" with each other and unable to interfere. What you're describing sounds like a different formulation of quantum mechanics altogether.

Comment: @MarkMoralesII Suppose that the initial state is pure (not mixed), and suppose that the system is closed (which seems to be implied by the phrase "global or universal wavefunction"). Time-evolution is unitary in a closed system, so the state remains pure forever. If "coherent" means "pure," then the answer would be that simple. But is that what the author meant by "coherent"? Did the author give a definition?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly As far as you are aware, is the initial quantum state of the universe said to have been pure or mixed?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Hmmm, in [this article](https://www.wired.com/2014/04/quantum-theory-flow-time/), physicist Seth Lloyd is quoted as saying, "The universe as a whole is in a pure state. But individual pieces of it, because they are entangled with the rest of the universe, are in mixtures."

Comment: Note that we could certainly model the whole universe as being in a mixed state (i.e. drawn from a probability distribution over the space of universes). However, every possible set of observations can be explained by a pure-state universe, so we usually don't bother worrying about the distribution from which our universe might have been drawn (i.e. modeling it as a mixed state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering only the many-worlds interpretation of quantum theory.

You can think of the universal wavefunction as a pure state (and if it is somehow not, just add qubits until it is one) and always stays that way. So if you have a wavefunction of the form
$$|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|\phi_{1}\rangle + |\phi_{2}\rangle \right)$$
then you can find $|\phi_{1}\rangle$ and $|\phi_{2}\rangle$ can interfere with each other just like normal.

When you start to think about observers it gets a bit more confusing but writing the universal wavefunction as:
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|o_{1}(t)\rangle\otimes |s_{1}(t)\rangle + |o_{2}(t)\rangle\otimes |s_{2}(t)\rangle \right).$$
Then the question becomes, can the systems $s_{j}$ interfere with each other, and the answer is yes, **but** only if/when the two observers match up with each other $$|o_{1}(t^*)\rangle = |o_{2}(t^*)\rangle.$$

If this happened then regardless of which path you took you'd have exactly the same thoughts at this time. It would also appear that this should only ever happen instantaneously, however when we are at times near $t^*$ we can always express $|o_{j}\rangle$ as some sum of the observer's state at the critical time $|0\rangle$ plus some small perturbation by state $|j\rangle$ that goes to zero as $t\rightarrow t^*$.

This argument is fairly simplified as the observer is made of well beyond trillions of qubits and so you probably don't have to worry about this looping procedure occurring and instead will only ever see interference if you can keep the coupling between the observer and the system sufficiently small (and so don't see interference arising due to interfering branches).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. You win the bounty! :)

Answer (score 4):

In the MWI, the total quantum state never collapses.
See this: https://thereader.mitpress.mit.edu/the-many-worlds-theory/.

The different "branches" of the world can and do interfere with each other.  The double slit interferometer is a clear example: each path the particle takes represents a different world.  In fact, I think it is correct to say that *all* quantum interference constitutes the interference between alternative "worlds'.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that wavefunction collapse does not occur under the Many-Worlds Interpretation and agree with your statement regarding interference. However, my question pertains to the possibility of interference between branches at the "global," universal level.

Comment: Not sure what that would mean.  At the "Global" level is where all the interference occurs.  Can you describe a scenario or consequence that would tell you that the interference does occur?